# Count # of characters in a row as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has about 100 columns and I want to count the number of characters in each column for a row.

In Excel, I would do something like `(Len(Concat(A2:CA2))`

```
df['newcolumn'] = ? in Pandas Python
```

Comment: `df['newcolumn'] = df['another_column'].str.len()` ?

Comment: Well technically, that question was about finding the length of a single column. While, I am looking for the total of all the columns in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If necessary first convert columns to strings, `sum` them for concanecate and last use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.len()
```

If need select columns by positions:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1:20].astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.len()
```

And if need only strings columns use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df['new'] = df.select_dtypes(object).sum(axis=1).str.len()
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to swap the order here... I'd imagine that incrementally building strings is going to be less efficient than getting the length then summing across the access, eg your last example: `df.select_dtypes(object).applymap(len).sum(axis=1)` or something

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[ len(" ".join(map(lambda x : str(x), list(df1.loc[index].values)))) for index in df1.index.tolist() ]

Comment: Welcolme, try to explain you solution so that people can understand the solution and not just copy paste your answer.